# Сделать изображение двуцветным на JS и CSS

Tags: canvas, javascript, css

Идея состоит в следующем. Есть каталог товаров. При наведении на картинку заказчику хочется сделать трансформацию в двуцветное изображение.

Хочется сделать это на стороне клиента по множеству причин (не хотел бы их тут сейчас все перечислять). Реально ли средствами CSS, JS, canvas сделать что-то подобное? Я, видимо, немножко устарел и отстал от современных технологий и не знаю, есть ли какие-нибудь средства для этого.

Пример до и после:

[image: до]

[image: после]

(Это только пример, я кривенько в пэинте как смог нарисовал, не бейте, но идея понятна.) Но нужна не черно-белая картинка в итоге, а под цвет дизайна (синевато-белый).

В общем, подскажите, в какую сторону копать и какие мануалы почитать? Да и в целом будет ли это сильно ресурсоемко?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://labs.voronianski.com/css3-grayscale/). Добавить всего-то пару правил. Если нужны более продвинутые фильтры, воспользуйся SVG. Там можно настраивать [цветовые матрицы, как ты хочешь](http://www.svgbasics.com/filters4.html).
Оба метода сейчас хорошо поддерживаются (в принципе), для небольших изображений - производительность хорошая.

Comment: Согласно табличке в этой статье http://habrahabr.ru/post/155353/ фильтры не поддерживает как минимум IE9, боюсь, заказчик этому будет не особо рад.

Насчет SVG - немного не пойму. Картинки нужно конвертировать в svg на сервере и отдавать клиенту уже svg файл? Или с помощью этой ерунды можно обрабатывать изображения на клиенте?

Comment: @IntellectSys, просто вставляешь изображение внутрь вот так: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag и устанавливаешь ему фильтр http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html . Поддержка так себе, но быстрого и производительного способа, наверное, на js нет. Только может если помещать в канвас и высчитывать смещение в чб вручную. Ну или на сервере делать

Comment: Впринципе это, я думаю, вполне подходит, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Придумал в своё время [такую конструкцию](http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/zm3wc9vr/) на `CSS transition` для плавного перехода при наведении цветного изображения в чёрнобелое и обратно. В принципе она подходит и для плавного перехода одного изображения в другое.

**HTLM:**

```
<div class="phone">
    <div class="phone-img-color"></div>
    <div class="phone-img-gray"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.phone {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 126px;
}

.phone div {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 126px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
       -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
         -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
            transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.phone-img-color {
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url("http://savepic.su/4832958.jpg");
}

.phone-img-gray {
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url("http://savepic.su/4822718.jpg");
}

.phone:hover .phone-img-color {
    opacity: 0;
}
.phone:hover .phone-img-gray {
    opacity: 1;
}
```